# R ggplot2 Dual y-axis facet wrap, one histogram and other line

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, facet-wrap, gtable

I have two facet wrapped plots, `p1` and `p2`

`p1`

[image]

`p2`

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis values line up for both plots, however the y-axis values differ quite drastically. I would like to overlay p2 onto p1, keeping the p1 y axis on the left and creating another p2 y-axis on the right.

This is what I have right now, but I am unsure of how to correctly combine grobs for p1 and p2.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

themer <- theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                panel.background = element_blank(),
                panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"),
                strip.background = element_rect(fill="#F8F8F8"))

p2 <- ggplot(normaldens, aes(y=density,x=predicted)) + 
        geom_line(color="red") + 
        facet_wrap(~ motif) + 
        labs(title=paste("Methylation Score:",motif_f[j]),x="Methylation Score",y="Density") +
        themer
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=score)) +
        geom_histogram( binwidth = bin_width,col="red",fill="blue",alpha=0.2) +  
        facet_wrap(~ motif) + 
        labs(title=paste("Methylation Score:",motif_f[j]),x="Methylation Score",y="Counts") +
        themer

###### COMBINE GROBS #######
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

combo_grob <- g2
pos <- length(combo_grob) - 1
combo_grob$grobs[[pos]] <- cbind(g1$grobs[[pos]],
                                 g2$grobs[[pos]], size = 'first')
panel_num <- length(unique(df1$z))
for (i in seq(panel_num))
{
  # grid.ls(g1$grobs[[i + 1]])
  panel_grob <- getGrob(g1$grobs[[i + 1]], 'geom_point.points',
                        grep = TRUE, global = TRUE)
  combo_grob$grobs[[i + 1]] <- addGrob(combo_grob$grobs[[i + 1]], 
                                       panel_grob)
}       


pos_a <- grep('axis_l', names(g1$grobs))
axis <- g1$grobs[pos_a]
for (i in seq(along = axis))
{
  if (i %in% c(2, 4))
  {
    pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == paste0('panel-', i), se = t:r))

    ax <- axis[[1]]$children[[2]]
    ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
    ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
    ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.5, "cm")
    ax$grobs[[2]]$x <- ax$grobs[[2]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.8, "cm")
    combo_grob <- gtable_add_cols(combo_grob, g2$widths[g2$layout[pos_a[i],]$l], length(combo_grob$widths) - 1)
    combo_grob <- gtable_add_grob(combo_grob, ax,  pp$t, length(combo_grob$widths) - 1, pp$b)
  }
}

pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == 'ylab', se = t:r))

ia <- which(g1$layout$name == "ylab")
ga <- g1$grobs[[ia]]
ga$rot <- 270
ga$x <- ga$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(1.5, "cm")

combo_grob <- gtable_add_cols(combo_grob, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia,]$l], length(combo_grob$widths) - 1)
combo_grob <- gtable_add_grob(combo_grob, ga, pp$t, length(combo_grob$widths) - 1, pp$b)
combo_grob$layout$clip <- "off"

grid.draw(combo_grob)
```

And I get this error, which I know has to do something with the way I'm combining the two gtables.

> Error in gList(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1, just = "centre",  : 
>     only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do a second y-axis within `ggplot2`, but what about plotting both density and histogram in a single plot and using bar labeling for the counts (instead of trying to hack a second y-axis). Here's an example (using the built-in `iris` dataset):

First, we'll calculate maximum values of density and count and use these to create scale factors that we'll use to programmatically ensure that the histogram and density plot have about the same vertical scale.

```
library(dplyr) 

# Find maximum value of density
densMax = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(dens = max(density(Sepal.Length)[["y"]])) %>%
  filter(dens == max(dens))

# Find maximum value of bin count
countMax = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species, 
           bins=cut(Sepal.Length, seq(floor(min(Sepal.Length)),
                                      ceiling(max(Sepal.Length)), 
                                      0.25), right=FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% filter(count==max(count))
```

Now we scale the histogram bars to the size of the density plot. `sf` is the scale factor:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, sf = countMax$count/densMax$dens)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill=hcl(195,100,65), colour="grey50", binwidth=0.25) +
  geom_density(colour="red", aes(y=..density.. * sf)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) + 
  themer
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could go in the other direction, and scale the density plot to the histogram:

```
# Scale histogram bars to size of density plot
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, sf = densMax$dens/countMax$count)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count..*sf), 
                 fill=hcl(195,100,65), colour="grey50", binwidth=0.25) +
  stat_bin(aes(label=..count.., y=..count..*0.5*sf), 
           geom="text", size=4, color="white", binwidth=0.25) +
  geom_density(colour="red") +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) + 
  themer +
  labs(y="Density")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a more general way of finding the right factor to scale by? I'm planning to use different data to generate these plots.